# Gravitational force between all objects. Java

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to implement the gravitational force between all objects. All attempts to implement something like that led to the strange behavior of objects. Here is one version of the code that I realized. And it does not work:

```
public void updateGravitation() {

    for (GravitationalBody aGravitationalBody : gravitationalBodies){
        double sumX = 0;
        double sumY = 0;
        for (GravitationalBody bGravitationalBody : gravitationalBodies){
            if (aGravitationalBody != bGravitationalBody) {

                double massMultiplication = aGravitationalBody.getMass() * bGravitationalBody.getMass();

                double distanceX = aGravitationalBody.getPosition().x - bGravitationalBody.getPosition().x;
                double distanceY = aGravitationalBody.getPosition().y - bGravitationalBody.getPosition().y;

                double r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceX,2) + Math.pow(distanceY,2));

                double force = G * massMultiplication/(r * r);

                double theta = distanceY / distanceX;

                sumX += force * theta;
                sumY += force * theta;

            }
        }
        aGravitationalBody.appleForce(sumX,sumY);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS Happy New Year!
PSS Sorry for bad english.

Comment: _"...led to the strange behavior of objects."_ What's strange to you will NOT be strange to me unless you specify why it is supposed to be strange.

Comment: Don't you find suspicious that the X-Y components of the force are always equal? Think again about `distanceY / distanceX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Don't you find suspicious that the X-Y components of the force are always equal? Think again about distanceY / distanceX

Thank you Margaret Bloom. I changed my code to:

```
public void updateGravitation() {

    for (GravitationalBody aGravitationalBody : gravitationalBodies){
        double sumX = 0;
        double sumY = 0;
        for (GravitationalBody bGravitationalBody : gravitationalBodies){
            if (aGravitationalBody != bGravitationalBody) {

                double massMultiplication = aGravitationalBody.getMass() * bGravitationalBody.getMass();

                double distanceX = aGravitationalBody.getPosition().x - bGravitationalBody.getPosition().x;
                double distanceY = aGravitationalBody.getPosition().y - bGravitationalBody.getPosition().y;

                double r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(distanceX,2) + Math.pow(distanceY,2));

                double force = G * massMultiplication/(r * r);

                sumX += -1*force * distanceX/r;
                sumY += -1*force * distanceY/r;

            }
        }
        aGravitationalBody.appleForce(sumX,sumY);
    }
}
```

Now it works fine